# iptables setting connmark but ip rule not matching

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, iptables

I am trying to set up an Ubuntu 17.10 VM to use multiple VPN connections, and to load balance connections between them.  I am trying to do that by running multiple openvpn clients, and trying to mark connections with iptables/connmark and using mode random to mark different connections with different values, then matching these with different VPN routing tables.  However, I am having no success, so I have tried to simplify the situation to try to understand what is going wrong.

I have reduced the scenario to a single VPN connection, with all my routing logic in a dedicated routing table, and trying to mark all packets to use that routing table.

If I force all traffic to use that table, it works ok.  If I try to mark all packets and then match that mark to use the table, it doesn't work.

Here are the rules that work:

```
0:      from all lookup local
10:     from all lookup VPN2
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

and here are the rules that do not work:

```
0:      from all lookup local
10:     from all fwmark 0x14 lookup VPN2
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

And here is my iptables mangle table that should mark everything:

```
# iptables -nvL -t mangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6785 packets, 464K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 8013  545K CONNMARK   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            CONNMARK restore
 7981  543K MARK       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MARK set 0x14
 7958  541K CONNMARK   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            CONNMARK save

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 6773 packets, 463K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4382 packets, 1132K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 4636 1159K CONNMARK   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            CONNMARK restore
 4516 1146K MARK       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MARK set 0x14
 4382 1132K CONNMARK   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            CONNMARK save

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4151 packets, 1116K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I understand my rules are a bit pointless here (the restore, before marking anyway) but I have just been trying to get it to mark everything to understand where the problem is.

Like I say, if I have everything use the VPN2 routing table, it works fine - and I can see connections marked with `20` (`0x14`) using `conntrack -L`

But if I try to have the routing based on the mark, it doesn't work, and the connection attempt isn't even visible in `conntrack -L`, even though I see the `SYN_SENT` status in `netstat`.  I also see the source IP is not my VPN tun interface, so the table is not being used.

Any advice to debug this is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: from what I'm understanding: when mangle is used in output it triggers a reroute check. that's this 2nd routing check that will use the fwmark rule. But the IP was already chosen at the 1st routing check. you could try doing also a nat. anyway you should concentrate on testing prerouting (from an other vm or network namespace) before testing output when output doesn't behave as expected. [Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg)

Comment: I still haven't figured it out completely yet, but I think you have put me on the right track with the 'rerouting' you have mentioned.  I found this post, and I think my filter table is filtering the packets before the rerouting happens:  https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/iptables-iproute2-rerouting-not-triggered-after-setting-mark-in-mangle-output-table-4175558452/

Comment: Many many thanks.  I have now managed to get connections randomly sent down different interfaces by temporarily removing all my filters (not sure how I'll re-add those), adding an SNAT rule in the nat/output chain, and setting this to 2 to prevent filtering of returning packets: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun1/rp_filter.  Thanks again